# Understanding error estimation used in mcmc package

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I am looking at [the MCMC Example tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmc/vignettes/demo.pdf) from [the package **mcmc** in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmc/). The code below is given there, where MCMC is used to compute the parameters in a logistic regression example.

```
library(mcmc) 

data(logit)
foo <- logit

out <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = foo, family = binomial())

x <- foo
x$y <- NULL 
x <- as.matrix(x)
x <- cbind(1, x)
dimnames(x) <- NULL
y <- foo$y

lupost <- function(beta, x, y){
  eta <- x %*% beta
  p <- 1/(1 + exp(-eta))

  logl <- sum(log(p[y == 1])) + sum(log(1-p[y == 0]))

  return(logl + sum(dnorm(beta, 0, 2, log = TRUE)))
}

set.seed(42)
beta.init <- as.numeric(coefficients(out))
out <- metrop(lupost, beta.init, 1000, x=x, y = y)
```

The idea is to compute the standard Monte Carlo error. Therefore

```
> apply(out$batch, 2, mean)
[1] 0.6531950 0.7920342 1.1701075 0.5077331 0.7488265
[6] 0.5145751 0.7560775 1.4973807 0.3913837 0.7244162
```

is used. My question is, **what is the meaning of the final 5 columns in the output of this command?** The tutorial states that it is somehow `E(X^2)`. But in which line is `X` generated? What is `X` here?

Comment: The code provided is taken from different sections, **2** and **4.1** in the tutorial. In the beginning of section **4**, it shows that a different `out` is calculated, and they clearly explain how and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run just the code you posted in your question above, then I only get 5 numbers:

```
apply(out$batch, 2, mean)
# [1] 0.5990174 0.8027482 1.1539329 0.4547702 0.7172724
```

It seems like the "tutorial" you are following is the `mcmc::demo` vignette. The vignette does all of the steps you posted above, *and then it also calculates*

```
out <- metrop(out, nbatch = 100, blen = 100, outfun = function(z) c(z, z^2))
```

followed by

```
apply(out$batch, 2, mean)
# [1] 0.6531950 0.7920342 1.1701075 0.5077331 0.7488265
# [6] 0.5145751 0.7560775 1.4973807 0.3913837 0.7244162
```

Here you can see that `outfun` is calculating X and X^2, and that you get estimates of E[X] and E[X^2] when you take the average using `apply()`.

The X's here appear to be draws from the posterior distribution of the model parameters (the betas). Notice that the Bayesian posterior means (the first 5 numbers) are quite close to the non-Bayesian point estimates calculated with `glm` in the fourth line of your code.